# Change the images of WPF image button on click

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls

I want to create an image button control which image source changes on button click. It is easy to create by directly passing normal/clicked image path values in control template trigger.

But my requirement is to create a generic image button which can be used at multiple places with different normal/clicked images. So that I can pass two image source in button control itself.

```
 <Button x:Name="buttonImage" local:ImageButton.NormalImage="Images/ImgA.png" local:ImageButton.PressedImage="Images/ImgB.png" Style="{DynamicResource ImageButtonStyle}" />
```

I was trying is with dependency attached properties and achieved the normal image by path binding with ancestor but not able to achieve pressed image on `IsPressed` trigger. In below code ImageButton is the class where the attached properties exist.

```
 <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="BtnBorder"  BorderThickness="1">
                        <Image  x:Name="ButtonImage" Source="{Binding Path=(local:ImageButton.NormalImage), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding local:ImageButton.PressedImage, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="BtnBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Let me know if you know a better way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Do you want your Button to display the alternative image after the click happened without falling back to the previous image automatically? Because that would be called a ToggleButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works for me:

```
public class ImageButton : ButtonBase
{
    private const string NormalImageSourcePropertyName = "NormalImageSource";
    private const string MouseOverImageSourcePropertyName = "MouseOverImageSource";
    private const string MouseOverPressedImageSourcePropertyName = "MouseOverPressedImageSource";
    private const string PressedImageSourcePropertyName = "PressedImageSource";

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(NormalImageSourcePropertyName, typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(MouseOverImageSourcePropertyName, typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverPressedImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(MouseOverPressedImageSourcePropertyName, typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(PressedImageSourcePropertyName, typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));

    static ImageButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));
    }

    public ImageSource NormalImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (ImageSource)GetValue(NormalImageSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(NormalImageSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ImageSource MouseOverImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (ImageSource)GetValue(MouseOverImageSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MouseOverImageSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ImageSource MouseOverPressedImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (ImageSource)GetValue(MouseOverPressedImageSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MouseOverPressedImageSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ImageSource PressedImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (ImageSource)GetValue(PressedImageSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PressedImageSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And the style is

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
                <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Source="{TemplateBinding NormalImageSource}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=MouseOverImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=MouseOverPressedImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=PressedImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It is a little more elaborate than your question, because it supports 4 images to make the user experience even better also when hovering.

An example where I use it :

```
<local:ImageButton DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="PART_CloseButton" Height="13" Width="13" Margin="3" NormalImageSource="/ICeTechControlLibrary;component/Images/exit-small.png" MouseOverImageSource="/ICeTechControlLibrary;component/Images/exit-small-hover.png" MouseOverPressedImageSource="/ICeTechControlLibrary;component/Images/exit-small-hover.png" PressedImageSource="/ICeTechControlLibrary;component/Images/exit-small-hover.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks Philip for your answer. You are passing the image paths in the button control with these  dependency property name as I wanted or in resource styles?

Comment: via the dependency properties, the styles are referring to those dependency properties, so yes, this is what you wanted.

Comment: Added an example for your convenience